# using ip to link to files in html

Tags: performance

wouldn't using ip instead of host name on a dedicated server make page load faster since you avoid the dns lookup? why isn't this done?

like using <script src="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/javascript.js>
<img src=same thing <link href=same thing? ??

Answer (score 1):

No, because the DNS lookup is cached.

Answer (score 0):

It's not done because it's not practical and doesn't bring any sensible performance gain

Comment: It typically takes 120 milliseconds for DNS to lookup the IP address for a given hostname. multiply this by un-parallel files and you get a different conclusion. and wow you responded fast!

Comment: as Darin said, the dns lookup is cached

Comment: i dont know the yahoo http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html page says reduce dns lookup. what are they talking about?

Comment: it says "My guideline is to split these components across at least two but no more than four hostnames" which is likely to be the case for a normal site